# Alembic inverting upgrade/downgrade (Flask-SQLAlchemy)

Tags: python, flask-sqlalchemy, alembic

I've been struggling with Alembic lately, I don't know why it is inverting the correct upgrade/downgrade changes.

I've created 2 new fields (about_me, last_seen) in the User model, run 'flask db migrate' and then looking at the version file I can see that the proper migration is in downgrade instead of upgrade.

I've tried to run db.create_all, db.drop_all, drop the alembic_version table with no success. Every time having the same result below, when I should have the DROP_TABLE commands in downgrade and the CREATE_TABLE commands in upgrade.

The only way I'm currently able to make it work is dropping the required tables and then manually copying and pasting the code from Downgrade to Upgrade.

**Migration file:**

```
def upgrade():
    # ### commands auto generated by Alembic - please adjust! ###
    op.drop_table('tutor_category')
    op.drop_table('tutors')
    op.drop_index('ix_categories_name', table_name='categories')
    op.drop_table('categories')
    op.drop_index('ix_users_email', table_name='users')
    op.drop_index('ix_users_first_name', table_name='users')
    op.drop_index('ix_users_last_name', table_name='users')
    op.drop_index('ix_users_timestamp_joined', table_name='users')
    op.drop_table('users')
    op.drop_index('ix_reviews_rating', table_name='reviews')
    op.drop_index('ix_reviews_timestamp', table_name='reviews')
    op.drop_table('reviews')
    # ### end Alembic commands ###


def downgrade():
    # ### commands auto generated by Alembic - please adjust! ###
    op.create_table('reviews',
    sa.Column('id', sa.INTEGER(), autoincrement=True, nullable=False),
    sa.Column('user_id', sa.INTEGER(), autoincrement=False, nullable=True),
    sa.Column('tutor_id', sa.INTEGER(), autoincrement=False, nullable=True),
    sa.Column('rating', sa.INTEGER(), autoincrement=False, nullable=True),
    sa.Column('timestamp', postgresql.TIMESTAMP(), autoincrement=False, nullable=True),
    sa.ForeignKeyConstraint(['tutor_id'], ['tutors.id'], name='reviews_tutor_id_fkey'),
    sa.ForeignKeyConstraint(['user_id'], ['users.id'], name='reviews_user_id_fkey'),
    sa.PrimaryKeyConstraint('id', name='reviews_pkey')
    )
    op.create_index('ix_reviews_timestamp', 'reviews', ['timestamp'], unique=False)
    op.create_index('ix_reviews_rating', 'reviews', ['rating'], unique=False)
    op.create_table('users',
    sa.Column('id', sa.INTEGER(), server_default=sa.text("nextval('users_id_seq'::regclass)"), autoincrement=True, nullable=False),
    sa.Column('first_name', sa.VARCHAR(length=64), autoincrement=False, nullable=False),
    sa.Column('last_name', sa.VARCHAR(length=64), autoincrement=False, nullable=False),
    sa.Column('email', sa.VARCHAR(length=120), autoincrement=False, nullable=False),
    sa.Column('profile_img', sa.VARCHAR(length=120), autoincrement=False, nullable=True),
    sa.Column('password_hash', sa.VARCHAR(length=128), autoincrement=False, nullable=False),
    sa.Column('timestamp_joined', postgresql.TIMESTAMP(), autoincrement=False, nullable=True),
    sa.Column('about_me', sa.VARCHAR(length=140), autoincrement=False, nullable=True),
    sa.Column('last_seen', postgresql.TIMESTAMP(timezone=True), autoincrement=False, nullable=True),
    sa.PrimaryKeyConstraint('id', name='users_pkey'),
    postgresql_ignore_search_path=False
    )
    op.create_index('ix_users_timestamp_joined', 'users', ['timestamp_joined'], unique=False)
    op.create_index('ix_users_last_name', 'users', ['last_name'], unique=False)
    op.create_index('ix_users_first_name', 'users', ['first_name'], unique=False)
    op.create_index('ix_users_email', 'users', ['email'], unique=True)
    op.create_table('categories',
    sa.Column('id', sa.INTEGER(), server_default=sa.text("nextval('categories_id_seq'::regclass)"), autoincrement=True, nullable=False),
    sa.Column('name', sa.VARCHAR(length=64), autoincrement=False, nullable=True),
    sa.PrimaryKeyConstraint('id', name='categories_pkey'),
    postgresql_ignore_search_path=False
    )
    op.create_index('ix_categories_name', 'categories', ['name'], unique=False)
    op.create_table('tutors',
    sa.Column('id', sa.INTEGER(), server_default=sa.text("nextval('tutors_id_seq'::regclass)"), autoincrement=True, nullable=False),
    sa.Column('user_id', sa.INTEGER(), autoincrement=False, nullable=True),
    sa.Column('price', postgresql.DOUBLE_PRECISION(precision=53), autoincrement=False, nullable=True),
    sa.ForeignKeyConstraint(['user_id'], ['users.id'], name='tutors_user_id_fkey'),
    sa.PrimaryKeyConstraint('id', name='tutors_pkey'),
    postgresql_ignore_search_path=False
    )
    op.create_table('tutor_category',
    sa.Column('tutor_id', sa.INTEGER(), autoincrement=False, nullable=False),
    sa.Column('category_id', sa.INTEGER(), autoincrement=False, nullable=False),
    sa.ForeignKeyConstraint(['category_id'], ['categories.id'], name='tutor_category_category_id_fkey'),
    sa.ForeignKeyConstraint(['tutor_id'], ['tutors.id'], name='tutor_category_tutor_id_fkey'),
    sa.PrimaryKeyConstraint('tutor_id', 'category_id', name='tutor_category_pkey')
    )
    # ### end Alembic commands ###
```

**Models.py**

```
class Users(UserMixin, db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    first_name = db.Column(db.String(64), index=True, nullable=False)
    last_name = db.Column(db.String(64), index=True, nullable=False)
    email = db.Column(db.String(120), index=True, unique=True, nullable=False)
    profile_img = db.Column(db.String(120), nullable=True)
    password_hash = db.Column(db.String(128), nullable=False)
    timestamp_joined = db.Column(db.DateTime, index=True, default=datetime.utcnow)
    about_me = db.Column(db.String(140), nullable=True)
    last_seen = db.Column(db.DateTime(140), default=datetime.utcnow)

    def set_password(self, password):
        self.password_hash = generate_password_hash(password)

    def check_password(self, password):
        return check_password_hash(self.password_hash, password)
    
    def avatar(self):
        digest = md5(self.email.lower().encode('utf-8')).hexdigest()
        return 'https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/{}?d=identicon'.format(
        digest)

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<User {}>'.format(self.username)

class Tutors(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'tutors'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('users.id'))
    price = db.Column(db.Float)

    # Connecting this field to the association table. 
    category = db.relationship("Categories", secondary="tutor_category")

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Tutor id {}'.format(self.user_id) + ' , price {}>'.format(self.price)

class Reviews(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'reviews'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('users.id'))
    tutor_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('tutors.id'))
    rating = db.Column(db.Integer, index=True)
    timestamp = db.Column(db.DateTime, index=True, default=datetime.utcnow)

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Review User: {}'.format(self.user_id) + ' Tutor: {}'.format(self.tutor_id) + ' Rating: {}>'.format(self.rating)

class Categories(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'categories'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(64), index=True)
    # Connecting this field to the association table. 
    tutor = db.relationship('Tutors', secondary="tutor_category")

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Category {}>'.format(self.name)

# Declaring the association table
tutor_category = db.Table('tutor_category',
    db.Column('tutor_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('tutors.id'), primary_key=True),
    db.Column('category_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('categories.id'), primary_key=True)
)

@login.user_loader
def load_user(id):
    return Users.query.get(int(id))
```

**Manage.py**

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_script import Manager
from flask_migrate import Migrate, MigrateCommand
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from app import app
from app import models

db = SQLAlchemy(app)

POSTGRES = {
    'user': 'richard',
    'pw': 'richard2906',
    'db': 'codetutors',
    'host': 'localhost',
    'port': '5432',
}

app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'postgresql://%(user)s:\
%(pw)s@%(host)s:%(port)s/%(db)s' % POSTGRES
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False

migrate = Migrate(app, db)
manager = Manager(app)
db.init_app(app)

manager.add_command('db', MigrateCommand)

def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config['DEBUG'] = True
    app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'postgresql://%(user)s:\
    %(pw)s@%(host)s:%(port)s/%(db)s' % POSTGRES
    app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False
    db = SQLAlchemy(app)
    db.init_app(app)
    return app

if __name__ == '__main__':
    manager.run()
```

**env.py**

```
from __future__ import with_statement

import logging
from logging.config import fileConfig

from sqlalchemy import engine_from_config
from sqlalchemy import pool

from alembic import context
from manage import db



# this is the Alembic Config object, which provides
# access to the values within the .ini file in use.
config = context.config

# Interpret the config file for Python logging.
# This line sets up loggers basically.
fileConfig(config.config_file_name)
logger = logging.getLogger('alembic.env')

# add your model's MetaData object here
# for 'autogenerate' support

# from app.models import Users, Tutors, Categories, Reviews
target_metadata = db.metadata

# from myapp import mymodel
# target_metadata = mymodel.Base.metadata
from flask import current_app
config.set_main_option(
    'sqlalchemy.url',
    str(current_app.extensions['migrate'].db.engine.url).replace('%', '%%'))
target_metadata = current_app.extensions['migrate'].db.metadata

# other values from the config, defined by the needs of env.py,
# can be acquired:
# my_important_option = config.get_main_option("my_important_option")
# ... etc.


def run_migrations_offline():
    """Run migrations in 'offline' mode.

    This configures the context with just a URL
    and not an Engine, though an Engine is acceptable
    here as well.  By skipping the Engine creation
    we don't even need a DBAPI to be available.

    Calls to context.execute() here emit the given string to the
    script output.

    """
    url = config.get_main_option("sqlalchemy.url")
    context.configure(
        url=url, target_metadata=target_metadata, literal_binds=True
    )

    with context.begin_transaction():
        context.run_migrations()


def run_migrations_online():
    """Run migrations in 'online' mode.

    In this scenario we need to create an Engine
    and associate a connection with the context.

    """

    # this callback is used to prevent an auto-migration from being generated
    # when there are no changes to the schema
    # reference: http://alembic.zzzcomputing.com/en/latest/cookbook.html
    def process_revision_directives(context, revision, directives):
        if getattr(config.cmd_opts, 'autogenerate', False):
            script = directives[0]
            if script.upgrade_ops.is_empty():
                directives[:] = []
                logger.info('No changes in schema detected.')

    connectable = engine_from_config(
        config.get_section(config.config_ini_section),
        prefix='sqlalchemy.',
        poolclass=pool.NullPool,
    )

    with connectable.connect() as connection:
        context.configure(
            connection=connection,
            target_metadata=target_metadata,
            process_revision_directives=process_revision_directives,
            **current_app.extensions['migrate'].configure_args
        )

        with context.begin_transaction():
            context.run_migrations()


if context.is_offline_mode():
    run_migrations_offline()
else:
    run_migrations_online()
```

I appreciate the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those in a similar problem, I was using Flask-Script Manager as 'python manage.py db migrate' then changed to 'flask db migrate' and the application started to recognise properly the Models/Tables.

Answer (score 1):

I just guess that also your db has changed when you moved over to `flask db migrate` instead of using the `flask_script` with `python3 migrate.py db migrate`.

It seems to be, that your database (at the time of your question) already contains the tables you want to migrate. When they are present but not used/mentioned/imported in your code it is obviously the right decision from alembic to remove them.

From this point of view an upgrade should delete the tables and a downgrade recreates them as before.

**Always import your models in your migration script (when using `flask_script`) and always apply the db changes with the `db upgrade` command instead of adding tables by yourself.**

This should lead to a correct upgrade script.

#### Regarding your code

- You could create your own `app` instead of importing it
- You have used the imported `app` variable to bind the SQLAlchemy instance but also you defined another `create_app` function which is unused? And you did a `db.init_app(app)` on that instance too (even it is created with `SQLAlchemy(app)`

I guess this leads alembic to look to the false `app` context where none oof your models where definded. Plus your db contains tables which are not mentioned in this `app`.

This is my migrate.py:

```py
from flask import Flask
from flask_script import Manager
from flask_migrate import Migrate, MigrateCommand
from models import * # contains 'db.Model' classes and instance of 'db'

app = Flask(__name__)
config_path = "config.json"
app.config.from_json(config_path)

# db = SQLAlchemy(app) # <-- the "normal way"
db.init_app(app) # <-- most likely if you have defined 'db' already in 'models.py'

migrate = Migrate(app, db)
manager = Manager(app)
manager.add_command('db', MigrateCommand)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    manager.run()
```